# Python custom sort

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I am trying to sort a list using Python's `sorted` function. In Python 3 the `cmp` keyword argument was removed. Unfortunately it seems that I cannot implement my algorithm using the `key` keyword argument since I need both objects in order to compare the data.

**Example Sorted Data**

```
59 59
59 3 1 1
59 4 3 3
61 1
61 10
61 237
61 1 1 1
```

**Compare Function**

```
NUM_RE = re.compile("[\d]+")
def compare(x, y):
    # Aggregate our data into integer arrays
    x_result = [int(x) for x in NUM_RE.findall(x)]
    y_result = [int(y) for y in NUM_RE.findall(y)]

    # Return if there is a non-zero difference in the first element
    statement_diff = x_result[0] - y_result[0]
    if statement_diff != 0:
        return statement_diff

    # Return if there is a non-zero difference between the lengths
    length_diff = len(x_result) - len(y_result)
    if length_diff != 0:
        return length_diff

    # len(x_result) == len(y_result)
    # Iterate over each item and return if there is a difference
    for i in range(1, len(x_result)):
        result = x_result[i] - y_result[i]
        if result != 0:
            return result

    # Results are the same
    return 0
```

What is the best method for sorting this data? Should I create a "wrapper object" that implements the `__eq___`, `__gt__`, `__lt__`, etc functions so I can use the default sorting function? Or is there another function included in the standard Python API that accomplishes the original behavior of `sorted`?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? I have a feeling it can be simplified quite a bit, also how does `min(x_result.groups(), y_result.groups())` work with range?

Comment: Wouldn't it also be `NUM_RE.findall` and have no groups?

Comment: The comparison function you provide isn't correct. There's no `find_all` method, and `findall` returns a list -- not a match object, as you seem to expect here. Could you provide a working comparison function that shows what you're actually looking for? If the comparison function actually produces a consistent order, then it should be possible to rewrite it as a `key` function.

Comment: @senderle sorry I have fixed the compare function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python already has the wrapper you describe, it's called [`functools.cmp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html)

Answer (score 3):

As a matter of fact, this can easily be implemented as a key function. The comparison function behaves just as if the strings had been converted into lists. So it's as simple as converting the string to a list of numbers:

```
NUM_RE = re.compile("[\d]+")
def seq_key(x):
    return [int(y) for y in NUM_RE.findall(x)]
```

In case you feel uncertain about that, try this test:

```
cmp_key = functools.cmp_to_key(compare)

def gen_rnd(n):
    seq = [[random.randrange(1, 100)
           for _ in xrange(random.randrange(2, 6))]
           for _ in xrange(n)]
    return [' '.join(map(str, x)) for x in seq]

def test(n):
    a = gen_rnd(n)
    return all(sorted(x, key=seq_key) == sorted(x, key=cmp_key)
               for x in a)

test(1000000)
```

This test doesn't check corner cases, but I'm pretty sure these are semantically identical.

You might ask "why bother taking the trouble to figure out the right `key` function?" Here's why:

```
>>> a = gen_rnd(10000)
>>> %timeit sorted(a, key=cmp_key)
1 loops, best of 3: 705 ms per loop
>>> %timeit sorted(a, key=seq_key)
10 loops, best of 3: 47.9 ms per loop
```

The key function is more than an order of magnitude faster! And the effect is more noticeable the larger the list gets. This is partially because list comparison is a fast built-in feature. But it's also because there's genuinely less work to do. The number of *comparisons* performed is O(n log n), but the number of key conversions performed is only O(n). So if you can shift some of your comparison work into a key function, you can get a good speedup.